# Schema.org for individuals who offer a service (like Uber drivers)

Tags: schema.org, rich-snippets

Schema.org includes `"provider":"person or organization"` for `@Type "Service"`. But what about reviewing these services offered?

```json
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Service",
      "aggregateRating": {
          "@type": "AggregateRating",
          "ratingCount": "25",
          "ratingValue": "3"
      }
}
```

[Google mentions](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/review-snippet) reviews can be applied to:

- Local businesses
- Movies
- Books
- Music
- Products

In regards to Schema.org data:

1. How do I define that this is an individual offering the service and being reviewed?
2. Do I want to do it this way or will Google ignore it?

Comment: https://schema.org/provider could work, but I don't think Google would use it.

Comment: 1.) What makes you think that `provider` is not suitable? You quoted that it can also be a `Person`. 2.) Even if Google ignores it, you might still want to use it -- or do you only want to add structured data that Google makes use of?

Comment: Thank you @unor for the comment. If Google won't display the rating in SERs I would think about using microformatting that they would display. The concept of reviewing individuals seems to be left out of their developer.google.com documentation for microformats. I find this surprising considering the reviewing of services by humans are very important but not used by Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I define that this is an individual offering the service […]?

As you note yourself, the [`provider`](https://schema.org/provider) property can be used to specify the service provider (which can be a `Person`).

```json
"@type": "Service",
"provider": {
  "@type": "Person"
}
```

> How do I define that this is an individual […] being reviewed?

It would probably be unusual to review the `Person` (instead of the `Service` this `Person` provides), but it’s possible with Schema.org.

```json
"@type": "Review",
"itemReviewed": {
  "@type": "Person"
}
```

If the review is for the service, simply replace `Person` with `Service`.

> Do I want to do it this way or will Google ignore it?

Neither services nor persons are listed among the things Google Search will display a [review rich result](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/review-snippet) or a [critic review rich result](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/critic-review) for. This doesn’t necessarily mean that they won’t display it, but it’s at least not documented.

Note that they document to support the review rich result for products, though, and Schema.org’s [`Product`](https://schema.org/Product) type can also be used for services:

> Any offered product or **service**.